# How can I interpret this determinant formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, determinant

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $A\in\mathbb{K}^{m\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$. Then:

\begin{equation}
\det{AB} = \sum_{i_1<i_2<\dots<i_m}
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1i_1} & a_{1i_2} & \dots & a_{1i_m} \\ 
a_{2i_1} & a_{2i_2} & \dots & a_{2i_m} \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
a_{mi_1} & a_{mi_2} & \dots & a_{mi_m}  \notag
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix}
b_{i_11} & b_{i_12} & \dots & b_{i_1m} \\ 
b_{i_21} & b_{i_22} & \dots & b_{i_2m} \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
b_{i_m1} & b_{i_m2} & \dots & b_{i_mm}  \notag
\end{vmatrix}.
\end{equation}

In my exercise I need to prove that this is true by using the Leibniz formula, but I am struggling to interpret this sum in the first place.

What would a computation using this formula e.g. for $A\in\mathbb{K}^{3\times 2}$ and $B\in\mathbb{K}^{2\times 3}$ look like?

Comment: You need $m \le n$ in order for the sum to be nonempty, so $m=3$ and $n=2$ is trivial case. (The left-hand side is zero since $AB$ has rank at most $2$, and the right-hand side is zero since you can't pick $i_1,i_2,i_3 \in \{ 1,2 \}$ such that $i_1 < i_2 < i_3$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula). For $A \in \Bbb K^{2 \times 3}$ and $B \in \Bbb K^{3 \times 2}$, here is what it looks like.
$$
\det(AB) = \det \pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22}}\pmatrix{b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}}
\\ \hspace{50 pt}+ \det \pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{13}\\ a_{21} & a_{23}}\pmatrix{b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{31}&b_{32}}
\\ \hspace{52 pt}+ \det \pmatrix{a_{12} & a_{13}\\ a_{22} & a_{23}}\pmatrix{b_{21}&b_{22}\\b_{31}&b_{32}}.
$$